# Emulating hardware via ethernet?

Tags: networking, emulation

I have an intersting idea I would like to see: is there any way to connect your LAN computers and use each other's  devices as being on the current device?

Eg.: I have a souncard connected to the other computer and would like to use it through my laptop connected via WLAN. The same could be applicable to monitors, keyboard, mouse, usb devices (sticks), etc.

Comment: Off-hand answer, no, an ethernet cable will not give you low enough latency to do this acceptably

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't always do this at the driver level because of bandwidth and latency constraints, although you can in some cases.

With that said, much of this functionality can be replicated by various software. For example, on Linux, [PulseAudio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PulseAudio) can play sound transparently from a network source. Keyboard and mouse can be shared over a LAN with [Synergy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synergy_(software)). USB devices can be shared with something like [this](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/) (USB/IP Project).

Devices like monitors that would require more bandwidth than most LAN connections can supply would not be well-suited to use with this kind of software, however.